# useEffect Setting Redux State multiple Times

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

Am new in React and am trying to create an Chat App and in my app there is section of channels
now here what i done for fetching channel

```
const [Channels, setChannelState] = React.useState([]);

  const ref = firebase.database();
  const loadedChannels = [];

  React.useEffect(() => {
    ref.ref("channels").on("child_added", snap => {
      loadedChannels.push(snap.val());
      setChannelState([...loadedChannels]);
    });
  }, []);
```

whenever new channel added it updates the local state

so my problem is here i want when page loads it basically get first channel from Channels State Array i.e *Channels* and set it to redux global state

here is my dispatcher

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    SetFirstChannel: channel => {
      dispatch({ type: "SET_FIRST_CHANNEL", payload: channel });
    }
  };
};
```

and in my reducer:

```
const iState = {
  currentChannel: ""
};

export const rootReducer = (state = iState, action) => {
  return {
    currentChannel: action.payload
  };
};
```

now how can i get the first element from channels array and store into the redux

here what i have done so far..
https://codesandbox.io/embed/quiet-wind-g9zxx
but this cause setting redux state multiple times

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the first channel every-time and only update it if the first channel changes, something like this should work:

```
React.useMemo(() => props.SetFirstChannel(Channels[0]), [Channels[0]]);
```

I set this up locally and checked. Let me know if it works. Cheers!

Comment: this works but when page loads initially my redux state set to null and again re-render then it set the value to redux state but when am trying to access to redux state via props am getting undefined  look here : https://codesandbox.io/embed/quiet-wind-g9zxx

Comment: That is how react works. useEffect runs after the initial render, similar to componentDidMount() and later like componentDidUpdate(). Hope this helps.

Comment: So now i have another class based component in which i have to fetch all the channels from redux global state i can do this by ComponentDidMount method but i am getting null because initially it store undefined in global redux state how can i resolve this? here in Chat.js you can get what i am taking about https://codesandbox.io/embed/quiet-wind-g9zxx

Comment: You don't have to get that from componentDidMount. When the channel updates, it will update on it's own because your component is connected to the redux store. 

Just keep a check if the channel is empty like you are already doing : <p>{this.props.channel ? "ok" : "loading"}</p>

Comment: Basically what I have to done is fetching some data from the firebase on the bases of channel that is stored in redux state when the page loads. so I have to add my fetching method in componentDidMount but in componentDidMount am getting null from redux strore [look chat.js] https://codesandbox.io/embed/quiet-wind-g9zxx

Comment: Oh now I get it. You want to use the channel to get your data? 
I used a hooks to recreate componentDidUpdate. I updated the project. Check it out. 
https://codesandbox.io/embed/quiet-wind-g9zxx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199127/discussion-between-paruchuri-p-and-himanshu-rahi).